# An easier way to define these variables?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$access_community = 1;
$access_content = 1;
$access_tools = 1;
$access_administrator = 0;
$access_moderator = 0;
```

Just wondering if there's an easier way to write this using an array? This seems like overkill.

Thanks!

Comment: This indeed looks like a case for an array, but it's hard to tell what to do because we don't know the context.

Comment: what is overkill in setting variables?

Comment: @Pekka; they will need to be access later using an if ($access_?? == 1) etc. @Col. Shrapnel Just seems like a waste of time writing all that when I'm sure there's a quicker way.

Comment: Sam, **every** variable is going to be used later in the code. Your answer to Pekka didn't actually answer anything.

Comment: Well, that's how I'm using it :).

Comment: Well you can't explain it using words of language. Need some practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could either do something like (sucks for readability):

```
$access_community = $access_content = $access_tools = 1;
$access_administrator = $access_moderator = 0;
```

Or as already been said, using an array:

```
$access = array('community' => 1,
                'content' => 1,
                'tools' => 1,
                'administrator' => 0,
                'moderator' => 0);
```

Comment: Then I can access those using echo $access_community (will echo 1?)?

Comment: with the first solution yes. with the array-solution you'll have to do `echo $access['community']`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. Thanks to all other answers too :).

Comment: while second one is sensible, the first one is terrible. these settings are going to be different on different pages for sure. And it will be hard as hell to get a picture of the page access rights looking into these lines.

Comment: That's why I said, that it sucks for readability. But it is a solution, otherwise it wouldn't have been built in php. I would also rather use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

If you had more variables, then something like:

```
$access = array( 'community' => 1, 'content' => 1, ... );
foreach ($access as $k => $v) {
    $real_name = 'access_' . $k;
    $$real_name = $v;
}
```

Might work, but it's not that nice, and probably even more overkill than your code is now. I think that what you have isn't too bad, to be honest!

If you're interested, this uses indirect references or ["variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to actually define new variables. I'm not too sure about scope here, however.

Of course, if you can, try and just use the array directly, rather than relying on the variables being there - arrays can be changed and passed around, unlike variables.

Comment: OK, it's not a very neat solution! :) It might be the only one if the OP really needs the variables to be defined like that, e.g. for interfacing with external code.

Comment: Heh, just looking for ideas :). In the future I could possibly have about 30 or 40 of these lines, so was thinking there must be an easier way :).

Comment: @Sam: In that case, I'd recommend going with the second solution in faileN's answer.

Comment: every time you are using a variable variable, you know for sure you are doing wrong

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: `goto` and `eval` have their uses as well.

Comment: yes, most of time you can say the same of these two too. especially if you are answering to the newbie programmers question.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I see your point. :) My answer isn't a very good one, but indirect references aren't *always* bad.

Answer (score -1):

Because you hardly can explain what are you doing and why, we can only guess.

It looks like some [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).
So, the only sensible way to set these variables is to store it in the database. Especially if there will be dozens of them in the future.

http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/ is probably what are you looking for

So, your variables will be assigned with values from  database.

As for the answer you asked - no, there is no other way to initialize different variables with different values. You have to explicitly set every variable value. So, you have to define a variable name and a variable value somehow. So,

```
$variable = value
```

is the most plain and way convenient way.
You can make it more complicated way, but at the core it remains the same: "variable name - variable value" pairs